# Passing extra argument to a return callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using a library function which is in this format:

```
let arr = [1,2,3]
arr.forEach((item, i) =>{
    doSomething(inputParam, (err, result)=>{
        ...
        //Use err and result
    });

})
```

`err` and `result` are set in the library function which I haven't developed.

How can I pass extra parameter `i` to the callback function?

**Note:** I want the `i` in each callback to correspond to the right index. Since they are asynchronous, by the time the are done they will all see the last value of i, which is not what I want. For example, the second callback should see i=2, and the third one should see i=3.

I need something like this:

```
let arr = [1,2,3]
arr.forEach((item, i) =>{
    doSomething(inputParam, (err, result, i)=>{
        ...
        //Use err and result
        console.log("i: ", i);
    });

})
```

Comment: Remove the `i` parameter after `result`, and just do a `console.log("i: ", i)`, it should work

Comment: You don't need to pass it doSomething...it is already in scope to be able to use inside that function call

Comment: only remove `i` from parameters of your callback. [only convert `(err, result, i)` to `(err, result)`].

Comment: You do not control the arguments to your callback.  Those are set by the caller which is the internals of the `doSomething()` function which you say is not something you control.  So, don't try to add things there that the caller isn't setting.  That will only mess up you.  So, instead, since you're using an inline callback, you can just directly access variables in the parent scope without defining them as arguments to the callback.  This is a nice feature of Javascript (inline callbacks  with access to parent scoped variables).

Comment: But I want the `i` in each callback to correspond to the right index. Since they are asynchronous, by the time the are done they will all see the last value of i, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not control the arguments to your callback.  Those are set by the caller which is the internals of the `doSomething()` function which you say is not something you control.  So, don't try to add things there that the caller isn't setting.  That will only mess you up.

Instead, since you're using an inline callback, you can just directly access variables in the parent scope without defining them as arguments to the callback.  This is a nice feature of Javascript (inline callbacks  with access to parent scoped variables).

Here's a runnable example:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
let inputParam = "something";

arr.forEach((item, i) => {
    doSomething(inputParam, (err, result) => {
        // you can access variables such as i in the parent scope here
        // from an inline callback

        //Use err and result
        console.log("i: ", i);
    });
});

function doSomething(param1, callback) {
    // simulate async callback
    setTimeout(function() {
        callback(null, "hello");
    }, 100);
}
```

---

If you ever need to use a callback that is not inline (like something defined in another module), you can create a small inline callback stub that can then access the parent scoped variables and can then call your externally defined function with the desired parameters.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
let inputParam = "something";

function yourExternalFunction(err, result, i) {
    // Use err and result and i
    console.log("i: ", i);
}

arr.forEach((item, i) => {
    doSomething(inputParam, (err, result) => {
        // you can access variables such as i in the parent scope here
        // from an inline callback
        yourExternalFunction(err, result, i) ;
    });
});

function doSomething(param1, callback) {
    // simulate async callback
    setTimeout(function() {
        callback(null, "hello");
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: I want the `i` in each callback to correspond to the right index. Since they are asynchronous, by the time the are done they will all see the last value of `i`, which is not what I want. Does i in this solution get the right value?

Comment: @Ari - No.  That's not an issue here (like it could be with a regular `for` loop) because each `i` is separately saved for each callback in the `.forEach()` callback.  Press the "Run code snippet" buttons to run them and see.  If you want your async operations to be sequenced (so the 2nd doesn't get called until the first is done), that's an entirely different question, but isn't something you stated in your question.

Comment: This answered my question: "because each i is separately saved for each callback.". Thanks!

Comment: @Ari - FYI, in a regular `for` loop where that issue can happen, if you use `let` as in `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { ... }`, then you also don't have the issue with `i` in async callbacks there either because `let` scopes each `i` separately for each run of the `for` loop.

Comment: @Ari - If this answered your question, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and also earn yourself some reputation points for following the proper procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt is close, just remove the `i` after `result`, and it will work

Here is a blog post on [JavaScript Scope](https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/)

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3]
arr.forEach((item, i) => {
  doSomething('inputParam', (err, result) => {
    console.log("i: ", i);
  })
})

function doSomething(param, callback) {
  callback('Error', 'Result')
}
```